# Json decode in PHP and how to read the key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json `$result = json_decode($result);` PHP
JSON EX:

```
  [
  {
      "X": "Teste1 X",
      "Y": "Teste1 Y",
      "Z": "Teste1 Z",
      "A": {
          "C": "Teste1 C"
      },
      "B": {
          "D": "Teste1 D"
      }
  }
  ]
```

How to read the key value "A" and "B"?

Key value "C" e "D" in "A" e "B"?

```
$result = json_decode($result);

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $strx    = $value->X;
    $stry    = $value->Y;
    $strz    = $value->Z;
    if($key == "A") {
        $strA = $value->C;
    }
    if($key == "B") {
        $strB = $value->D;
    }
    $str1    = $value->1;
    $str2    = $value->2;
    $str3    = $value->3; 
}
```

Comment: The title of your question is meaningless. Your problem is not about the variable `$result` or the syntax of calling `json_decode`, but more about "How to access the result of json_decode for nested object in PHP?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your JSON is wrapped in `[]` it will be treated as an indexed array and as such your `$key` variable will be the index of the value (e.g. 0,1,2,etc).

So to answer your question, to get the value of `A` replace

```
if($key == "A") {
    $strA = $value->C;
}
if($key == "B") {
    $strB = $value->D;
```

With

```
if( isset($value->A)) {
    $strA = $value->A->C;
}
if(isset($value->B)) {
    $strB = $value->B->D;
```

What are you trying to get with `$value->1`, `$value->2`, and `$value->3`?

Comment: Perfect very good!!!
I knew it was something like [], but did not know how to do it from there.

Thank you and GO GO GO and #WORKHARD !!!

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is the the way we can easy get the all the value to the particular JSON.

```
<?php

$result = json_decode('{
      "X": "Teste1 X",
      "Y": "Teste1 Y",
      "Z": "Teste1 Z",
      "A": {
          "C": "Teste1 C"
      },
      "B": {
          "D": "Teste1 D"
      }
  }');

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
   if($key == "A") {
        $strA = $value->C;
       echo $strA;
       echo "<br/>";
    }else if($key == "B") {
        $strB = $value->D;
        echo $strB;
        echo "<br/>";
   }else{
       echo $value;
       echo "<br>";
   }

}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `true` as second parameter to `json_decode()` in order to get the result in associative array format:

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

Then you can simply use the array to get the values you want:

```
$valueA = $result[0]['A'];
$valueCinA = $result[0]['A']['C'];
```